# Connecting Vertica as Django backend

Tags: python-3.6, vertica, django-2.1

I want to connect Vertica as the database backend for my Django application. Officially no support is provided by Django to it. I googled this problem and found this:
https://github.com/rutube/django_vertica_backend

The code which is written in this git hub returning following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rksharma/ccChatBot/django_vertica_backend/vertica/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.creation'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-

    packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
        self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
        return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 125, in load_backend
        ) from e_user
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'vertica' isn't an available database backend.
    Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
        'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: What is your Django version? It looks like it works with Django versions up to 1.7: https://github.com/rutube/django_vertica_backend/issues/12

Comment: I am using 2.0 django version.

Comment: as @Selcuk said it works with django 1.7 only.

Comment: Buddy is there any way where we can run it with 2.0.

Comment: Since it is open source your best bet is to fix the issues yourself and make it work with Django 2.0, then open a pull request to the maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of now. We can create some custom functionality to do so.